# How to mix polygon extrusion and different altitude modes in KML?

Tags: 3d, kml

I want to create boxes by simply extruding polygons but with special "floors". I've been able to find several existing solutions for the extrusion problem. The remaining problem is that the "floor" of my boxes do not fit with the altitude modes provided by the [KML reference](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#altitudemode). I want to be able to create floors with specifications like "max (100m absolute, 50m above ground)".

I don't see any simple solutions. I could do a grid sampling to get ground altitude (I'm already doing this for something else) and generate only absolute altitude. But I'm afraid that I will have problems in areas with too many mountains if the sampling is too sparse, or I will have a huge KML file if the sampling is too dense.

Comment: Can you sample based on the specific case? Mountains=detailed sampling; flat-lands = less detailed

Answer (score 2):

So combine

Absolute Extruded Polygons
http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/interactive/index.html#./Polygons/Polygons.Absolute_Extruded.kml

and

Relative Extruded Polygons

http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/interactive/index.html#./Polygons/Polygons.Relative_Extruded.kml

and
Relative Polygons
http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/interactive/index.html#./Polygons/Polygons.Relative.kml

(copy and paste the code into each other and set the altitude by the offset of the lower building polygon)